# How to delete multiple installs / versions of Microsoft Office

Tags: microsoft-office

Office Office Everywhere -- I work in a small company where "IT Services" is the person who knows the most about any given software. I'm running Windows 10 with Office 365 Business

My Outlook runs very slow. Reading various [tips](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-does-my-outlook-take-so-long-to-load-and-i/8f3b7b5d-1fa3-49ac-b035-a0c4262789bb) to improve performance, it's suggested I find a file in the Microsoft Office folder under Program Files. However, when I looked I found several,

This,

```
Directory: C:\Program Files
   ...
d-----        10/1/2018  10:30 PM                Microsoft Office 15
```

And,

```
Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)
...
d-----        2/16/2019   8:15 PM                Microsoft Office
   d-----       11/14/2018   7:32 AM                Office14
   da----        10/1/2018  10:29 PM                Office15
   d-----        2/16/2019   8:18 PM                Office16
...
d-----         2/4/2014   1:26 PM                Microsoft Office 15
```

Looks like this is the version I'm using given the LastWriteTIme date, `C:\Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Office \ Office16`

Looking into `Settings > Apps & Features` I find only one version of Microsoft Office 365 Business, so I don't see Settings as useful to manage these additional folders. Maybe they're just 'traces' of the older versions and not full versions? I don't know enough about Windows apps to be sure.

Assuming the first step to troubleshooting is to remove older versions, and if I don't care about old data stored with these older versions, can I safely "delete" the other directories and their contents? Of course, anytime you ask that question, you're asking for trouble. Maybe there's a more Window-savvy way to do this. On Linux you can rename a directory and "break references". Will that work on Windows? What else can I do?

Comment: I would not delete them unless you are sure of what the consequences are, when Office is upgraded some of the old files and folders are left behind, best left alone.

Comment: If you are using Office 365, then Office 16 is the correct folder, the previous folders exist due to previous builds of Office 365 being installed.  You should absolutely NOT delete them.

Comment: _"some of the old files and folders are left behind"_ so what I said, 'traces' of older versions, but not full apps?

Comment: _"You should absolutely NOT delete them."_ Can you `.bak` them to test if they _can_ be removed? Or does Windows use a different system than the path name? (naively I'm thinking about 'the registry', but I honestly don't understand what all it does.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use Revo Uninstaller and uninstall what you do not want to. It also searches registry entries and removes them as well.

Comment: I've fallen into the Windows rabbit hole...and I can't get up.